# Restkit 0.22.0 and iOS 7 RKObjectManager postObject not generating JSON data

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I receive this error when I attempt to use postObject in XCODE 5 for iOS 7:

Here is the error message without the URLs which point to https:// service

```
E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:542 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/html" UserInfo=0xb9a44f0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"status": "ok"}, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x8dd14c0> { URL: http:

NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xb998d30>

{ status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 16;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Any object the I put in postObject method just returns text/html and not JSON.  I does not appear to use the requestDescriptor or requestMapping that I defined.  Its simply posting the object as text/html.

Is there another method of posting using RestKit?

Is there a fix or workaround for this issue?

Here's my code sample:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; // objectClass == NSMutableDictionary
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"email", @"nickname"]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[RegisterDeviceInfo class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];


RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_uuidURL]];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

RegisterDeviceInfo *deviceInfo = [RegisterDeviceInfo new];
deviceInfo.email = email;
deviceInfo.nickname = nickname;

// This is not accepted by the postObject and mapped to JSON object using above mappings and requestDescriptor


NSLog(@"deviceInfo is: %@", deviceInfo);

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:deviceInfo path:(_uuidURL)               parameters:nil success: nil failure: nil];

NSLog(@"deviceInfo is: %@", deviceInfo);
```

Comment: Wain-  I have added the complete error message.  I thanks you for your help.

Comment: Wain: ps- I do have Restkit 0.22.0  I will change the version on this posting

Answer (score 0):

You should show the rest of the error (the lines before what you show). This is about the response, not the request. An HTML response often means an error message and you need to see what that is to know what's wrong.

The issue appears to be that you are using `(_uuidURL)` as the `path` when you call `postObject` but that it is the full URL.

The `path` should be relative to the base URL that was used to create the object manager. i.e.

```
baseURL = @"www.myserver.com/"

path = @"mycontent"
```

Comment: p.s. you should also upgrade to RestKit 0.22.0